# AJAX Control Toolkit HTML editor extender mess up hyperlinks

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, toolkit, htmleditorextender

I have a problem with ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit HTML editor extender. Some links contain "url" for example http://yourlisten.com/foo/bar when used as hyperlink on post back change to plain text _link.

```
<a href="http://yourlisten.com/foo/bar">link</a>
```

it changes to _link. Has anyone had same problem?

Comment: Are you saying that the URL in the href is changing to "_link"?